# Reinstalled Wamp and get Error establishing a database connection

Tags: database, wamp

Hi I can't access my local website.
Is there any way I can solve this?

I just reinstalled Wamp without doing any backups.

I got the error: Error establishing a database connection

The wp-config file looks the same

Comment: If you reinstalled to the same folder, you will have destroyed parts of the MYSQL databases. NEVER install WAMPServer over the top of an existing WAMPServer!

Comment: Yes I reinstalled in the same folder.

Comment: Where your database(s) INNODB or MYISAM? Do you have a backup?